# An ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND when the URL is rewritten using mod_rewrite for proxying

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy

This directive will redirect *example.com* into *example.info/es/test.php* :

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.info/es/test.php [R]
```

This directive will make *example.com* **ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND** instead of rewriting it into *example.info/es/test.php* :

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.info/es/test.php [P]
```

The web host is *HostGator* and they said the `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are enabled. I think, using `mod_rewrite` for proxying doesn't work with their server..

**ERROR LOG:**

```
[Wed Dec 25 10:45:05 2013] [alert] [client 112.210.128.107] /home2/USER/public_html/example.com/.htaccess: LoadModule not allowed here 
[Wed Dec 25 10:45:11 2013] [alert] [client 112.210.128.107] /home2/USER/public_html/example.com/.htaccess: LoadModule not allowed here 
[Wed Dec 25 10:47:39 2013] [error] [client 181.160.101.118] File does not exist: /home2/USER/public_html/example.com/es 
[Wed Dec 25 10:47:49 2013] [error] [client 112.210.128.107] File does not exist: /home2/USER/public_html/example.com/es
```

I'd try a lot of testings and I doesn't know the exact line of the error *(but I think it's the last two lines)*..

Comment: use something:
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Looks like you have `LoadModule` in your .htaccess. Can you post your complete .htaccess here?

Comment: @anubhava My customer said "I contacted the help again and a guy fixed. Apparently it had nothing to do with the htaccess file, it was the WordPress code handling the redirect via the siteurl variable." Is this true? How can a WordPress siteurl variable handle the redirect from my customized page?